# Unsuccessfully POST requests to an API

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am using the python requests module to send a post request to the BestBuy API to add a product to the cart. But the request is loading until it times out.

My code:

```
import requests
payload={"items":[{"skuId":"5712666"}]}  
headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'}
requests.post('https://www.bestbuy.com/cart/api/v1/addToCart', data=payload, headers=headers)
```

You can find the request-response on the BestBuy site when you press add to cart.

I think it may be the access-control-allow-origin: https://www.bestbuy.com which blocks my request, but I am not 100% sure, I am kind of new. Any workarounds?